# \caption outside float error

Tags: tables, labels

I cannot label my table. I feel it is because of the rotation that has been done. What can I do?

[image: Output according to the code given]

```
\begin{center}

\begin{adjustbox}{angle=90}

\begin{tabulary}{1.4\textwidth}{m{50mm}^C^C^C^C^C^C^C} 

\hline
\rowstyle{\bfseries}
& Openpilot & Pixhawk & Aeroquad & Arducopter & Paparazzi & Mikrokopter & Multiwii \\
\hline
\rowcolor{lightgray}
\rowstyle{\bfseries}
Filters and models & & & & & & & \\
\hline
Estimation & EKF & EKF & NCF/KF & NCF/KF & NCF/KF & LCF/KF & LCF/KF \\
\hline
Complete INS model & \checkmark & \checkmark & \--- & \--- & \--- & \--- & \--- \\
\hline
\rowcolor{lightgray}
\rowstyle{\bfseries}
Special Features & & & & & & & \\
\hline
Multi-cell Platform & \checkmark & \--- & \--- & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \--- \\
\hline
GPS navigation with checkpoints & $\Delta$ & $\Delta$ & \--- & \checkmark & \checkmark & $\Delta$ & $\Delta$ \\
\hline
Vision-based indoors flight & \--- & \checkmark & \--- & \--- & \--- & \--- & \--- \\
\hline
\rowcolor{lightgray}
\rowstyle{\bfseries}
Flight Control & & & & & & & \\
\hline
Heading control & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark \\
\hline
Position control & $\Delta$ & $\Delta$ & \--- & \checkmark & \checkmark & $\Delta$ & $\Delta$ \\
\hline
Altitude control (barometer) & \checkmark & $\Delta$ & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark \\
\hline
Altitude control (GPS) & $\Delta$ & $\Delta$ & \--- & \checkmark & \checkmark & $\Delta$ & $\Delta$ \\
\hline
Altitude control (SONAR) & \--- & \--- & \checkmark & \checkmark & \--- & \--- & \--- \\
\hline
Altitude control (O.F.Camera) & \checkmark & \checkmark & \--- & \--- & \--- & \--- & \--- \\
\hline
Open software license & GPL & GPL & GPL & LGPL & GPL & \--- & GPL \\
\hline

\end{tabulary}
\caption{Simple table}
\label{tab:example}
\end{adjustbox}

\end{center}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! This is probably because  you're missing a `table` environment.

Comment: Can you give me an idea of how to fix it without changing the layout as given in the picture? @Bernard

Comment: Either use sidewaystable from the rotating package to rotate your table or the captionof command from the caption package to add a caption to a non-floating tabular.

Comment: You can also use a landscape environment from pdflscape (or rotating) and a table [p].  There is an automatic \clearpage before and after to prevent anything from floating in or out.